# Using global variables inside functions using the `let` construct

Tags: let-binding

Have the following code but want to use `let` in the function `blink-cursor-timer-function`.  Have started doing the changes but do require some assistance with it.  The variable names `veak-indicator-point`, `veak-indicator-colour` are long, and want to shorten them.  A good way is to use local variables within a `let` construct, but keeping the long descriptive names present.  I do not think I can remove the variable `veak-indicator-point`, replace it with a local variable, and still have the cursor change colour upon blinking.

```lisp
    (defvar veak-indicator-point 0
      "Sets colour of cursor.")
    
    (defvar veak-indicator-colour
      (list "#FFA500" "#8A8AFF" "#FF6161" "#61FF61"
        "#FFFF00" "#E859E8" "#FFFFFF" "#FFC370" "#C370FF")
      "Sets colours for cursor.")
    
    (defun blink-cursor-timer-function ()
      "Blinks the cursor"
    
      (when (not (internal-show-cursor-p))
        (when (>= veak-indicator-point (length veak-indicator-colour)) 
        (setq veak-indicator-point 0))
        (set-cursor-color (nth veak-indicator-point veak-indicator-colour))
        (setq veak-indicator-point (+ 1 veak-indicator-point)))
      (internal-show-cursor nil (not (internal-show-cursor-p)) ))
```

I have started with the following

```lisp
     (defun blink-cursor-timer-function ()
      "Blinks the cursor"
    
      (let ( (i veak-indicator-point)
             (n (length veak-indicator-colour)) )
        
        (when (not (internal-show-cursor-p))
          (when (>= i n) (setq i 0))
          (set-cursor-color (nth i veak-indicator-colour))
          (setq i (+ 1 i))
          (setq veak-indicator-point i))
        (internal-show-cursor nil (not (internal-show-cursor-p))) )))
```

Comment: The question is unclear. Say what change you want to make to the code. What does "use let binding for blinking cursor" mean?

Comment: AFAICT the actual question has nothing to do with cursors, blinking or otherwise.

Comment: You are right.  Should I change the title?

Answer (score 1):

`let` bindings are not *aliases* for variables.  They are independent variable names (with either lexical or dynamic scope) to which you are assigning a value.  If you were to subsequently assign a new value to your `let`-bound `i` variable, that would have no effect on any other variable.

Such bindings are only valid for "shortening" purposes in a purely read-only context.

In any case, the names are not that long, and I think `(>= i n)` is worse as you now need to look elsewhere in the code to find out what `i` and `n` are.  I suggest not doing any of this.

---

Edit for comments:

> I keep within 72 characters, which is more compact than usual

This is within 72 characters:

```el
        (when (>= veak-indicator-point
                  (length veak-indicator-colour))
```

Actually, that's within 72 even on a single line, but you get the
point -- you are always free to format code across multiple lines.
Doing so is normal, and Emacs will indent appropriately.

Comment: I keep within 72 characters, where is more compact that usual,  You are correct, as what I am doing is basically shortening in a read-only context.